# Encoding issue with MsAccess/mysql - not displaying accent marks properly

Tags: mysql, ms-access, character-encoding, diacritics, linked-tables

I need to migrate some data we have in Access tables to mysql. I have used Mysql as a backend and MsAccess as a frontend before so I figured this was a no brainer. In the mysql/Access combo that works the mysql tables are in latin1_swedish and both mysql and access render accent marks properly.

In this new database however the accent marks are not displaying properly. I've tried alternating the mysql table collation from utf8 to latin1 to latin1_swedish but it isn't working.

What it does is this:

```
Enter ç directly into mysql{
    Mysql displays ç
    Access displays Ã§
}
Enter ç directly into access link table{
    Mysql truncates the accentmark and everything after it.
}
```

I don't know why it works fine in one, and not in another. Any suggestions?